# Form Submission after dynamic addition of elements not framing the proper query-string

Tags: html, forms, query-string, form-submit

I have created a form with 2 input text fields in a jQuerymobile page. But On click of some button which is outside this form, I am dynamically adding 2 more input fields to this form inside the div "ratingInfo".

```
<form id="rate" method="GET" action="Ratings" data-ajax="false"  onsubmit="return getRating();">
                    <label for="regid">Enter Registration ID : </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="regid" id="regid" name="regid" data-mini="true" data-ajax="false" style="width:240px;"/>
                    <fieldset style="margin-top:30px;" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
                        <legend>Rate the session our of 5 :</legend>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="rating1" value="1" checked="checked">
                        <label for="rating1">1</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="rating2" value="2">
                        <label for="rating2">2</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="rating3" value="3">
                        <label for="rating3">3</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="rating4" value="4">
                        <label for="rating4">4</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="rating5" value="5">
                        <label for="rating5">5</label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div id="ratingInfo" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; color:rgb(177, 175, 175);"></div>                  
                    <button data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" type="reset" >Reset</button>
                    <button data-inline="true" data-transition="flow" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" data-ajax="false" data-theme="b">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

jQuery that I used in getRating() method to add dynamic elements is :

```
$( "#ratingInfo" ).empty();
$( "#ratingInfo" ).append( "<span >Session ID - </span><input type='text' style='width:240px; color:rgb(177, 175, 175);' name='eventId' id='eventId' disabled='true'>" );
$("#eventId").val(eventId);
$( "#ratingInfo" ).append( "<br/><span>Session Description - </span><input type='text' style='width:240px; color:rgb(177, 175, 175);' name='eventDesc' disabled='true' id='eventDesc'>" );
$("#eventDesc").val(eventDesc);
```

When I Submit the form, the query-string(in the URL) has only 2 parameters that is "regId" and "radio".
The remaining 2 input fields "eventId" and "eventDesc" are not added in the URL as well. 
But onclick of reset button, all the fields including dynamically added fields are also reset.

What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I have resolved the issue.

Inside the "ratingInfo" div, I created input elements.
For them, I have given values through jquery.

I have added styles to "ratingInfo" div as:

```
display:none;
```

so that it is not visible.

Thanks.